# how to call to self-invocation function

Tags: javascript, self-invoking-function

Im trying to call to self-invoking function this way:

```
  (function fullscreen(){
    alert("test");
  })();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    fullscreen();
  });
```

it works only once. no response on window.resize
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing does not make sense. Why is `fullscreen` self-invoking? Just do this:

```
function fullscreen() {
  alert("test");
}

fullscreen();

$(window).resize(fullscreen);
// or
$(window).resize(function () {
    fullscreen();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you instantiate a function using the syntax typically employed for self-invoking functions, you're creating an **anonymous** function even though you give it a name.  In a function instantiation *expression*, the name you give after the `function` keyword is bound *inside* the function, and not outside.

(That's actually not true in Internet Explorer, but that's because Internet Explorer is broken.)